# CMake error while building MultiTarget-tracker library

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, video-tracking

I'm trying to build [Multitarget-tracker](https://github.com/Smorodov/Multitarget-tracker) using CMake in windows. Initially I had this warning below:

```
You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package)
```

I manually pointed out the directory of build version of OpenCV library and tried to **build**. I referred this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12074/cmake-opencv_dir/) while building. I now get this warning:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:23 (FIND_PACKAGE):
Found package configuration file:
  C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib/OpenCVConfig.cmake
but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be NOT FOUND.
```

I tried to check the `OpenCV_FOUND` variable, but after I press 'configure' again, it automatically unchecks.

Comment: You're not supposed to check `OpenCV_FOUND` manually: it's a variable set by `OpenCVConfig.cmake` to tell CMake if OpenCV was found or not. If it is set to `FALSE`, this means your installation of OpenCV is not valid according to the package. How did you install/compile OpenCV? What is the content of `OpenCVConfig.cmake`?

Comment: Yes, I did not install OpenCV properly. Thank you for your comment. Would you post this comment as the answer so that I can accept it? @wasthishelpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to check `OpenCV_FOUND` manually: it's a variable set by `OpenCVConfig.cmake` to tell CMake if OpenCV was found or not.

The fact it was set to `FALSE` is the sign your installation of OpenCV is not valid according to the package. Installing OpenCV properly is the solution.